# Parsing a nameless JSON array in Java

Tags: java, json, arrays

I'm trying to parse a nameless JSONArray returned from a POST request this format:

```
[{"key": value},
{"key": value},
{"key": value}]
```

I assumed I would just be able to call the array using this segment of code:

```
JSONArray resArr = result.getJSONArray("");
```

where `result` is the JSONObject returned by the POST, but I'm getting

```
Cannot parse json request result: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]
```

Is there some other way to call `getJSONArray` so that I can get an JSONArray without a key?

Answer (score 3):

### The correct way:

Parse this as an array using [`JSONArray(String)`](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html#JSONArray%28java.lang.String%29)<sup>1</sup>:

```
JSONArray myJsonArray = new JSONArray(resultAsString);
```

### The hacky way:

As a quick hack for this, you could consider building a valid JSON object. Simply concatenate `{"wrappedArray":` to the beginning of the string you have, and `}` to the end. You should then be able to parse this and call `getJSONArray("wrappedArray")` to get this array.

<sup>1</sup> This is a link to a javadoc that you can use to get more details on how to use your JSON library.

Comment: Neither of these methods worked, I received the same error message using both of them.

Comment: Can you print the concatenated strings? Something else is likely at play here.

Comment: Found the issue. The default JSON package refuses to accept `[` as it's initial character. `result` cannot be stored as a JSONObject.

Comment: There is no point in "wrapping" the array, as any JSON parser can handle an array.

Comment: @wwpieeater -- It's an **ARRAY**, so you parse it with **JSONArray**.  Go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.

Comment: wwpieeater and @HotLicks: I'm no longer keeping track of, or updating this post, as to be honest, I've mostly forgotten the documentation and use of org.json JSON in Java. I do recognize, however, that as wwpieeater does not have reputation to chat, that is not a viable option for a discussion about use of the JSON library.

Comment: @hexafraction - You brought it on yourself by editing that (supposed) answer.

Comment: @HotLicks Fair enough, I just cannot help in any way in terms of the actual content--formatting and post quality is still something I'm checking on every so often with my posts.

Answer (score -2):

The default JSON package refuses to accept `[` as it's initial character. Therefore, `result` cannot be stored as a JSONObject. What you (well, I) need to do, is store `result` as a JSONArray as soon as it it stored locally. Any attempt to access or modify the Array will return the [ parsing error. So, in order to access the JSONArray, you'll need to re-write your POST method to be able to return JSONArrays as well (practically, copy and paste the method, changing types and names). This should solve the type issue, as `[` is the expected starting character for a JSONArray.